# Unable to browse artifacts on Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.3.0-01

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

I have created a maven plugin, this is dependent on a series of JARS. i have uploaded these JARs and poms to the relevant location on the server under nexus-data/blobs/maven-thirdparty/{group-id}.

when i run a task to "Rebuild Maven repository metadata" and "Rebuild repository index" these files does not appear when i try and browse the files http://{nexus-server}:port/#browse/browse/assets.

How can i have nexus server recognize the files in the repository?

Comment: How have you uploaded them? Via GUI of Nexus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will look to that in future. I posted this same question to Sonatype forum and they assisted me with a utility that assists with this and it worked perfectly.

https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools/tree/master/maven-repository-provisioner

Thanks to Peter Lynch - https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/236210187-How-do-I-export-import-a-Maven-2-format-repository-over-HTTP-

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work, although it did in Nexus Repo 2. There currently is no mechanism for adding jars in to the blobstore in this way. We've intentionally added the blobstore and all that goes along with it so that we can do more fun things with searching, metadata, etc... that were much more difficult with a system that just has files on a path. What I might suggest instead is using something like this:

[Nexus Exchange - Nexus Repository Import Scripts](http://exchange.sonatype.com/details?extension=4969301365)

[GitHub Repo for Scripts](https://github.com/darthhater/nexus-repository-import-scripts)

That should help you get the JARs into Nexus Repository 3, into a repo of your choice. I maintain that repo, so if you run into issues, create an issue and I'll see what I can do to help you out! ~Sonatype Community Nerd